# Show event saved in MYSQL with PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar

i'm currently making an events calendar and i'm using a template for the calendar. I have an "inconvenient" tho show the events... I'm saving correctly the data in the mysql db but i don't know how to show the info.

DB: table: eventos

```
id | descripcion | hora | fecha
```

! The "fecha" field saves the time like JS provide E.G.: "Thu Mar 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)"

PD: In js the var title is refered to the field "hora" in mysql and is a time input in the form but for don't be in troubles with the code in JS I decided for keep the id "title" and don't change this for "hour".

PHP code with the info:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM eventos";
$queryEventos = msqli_query($conexion,$query);
$eventos = mysqli_fetch_array($queryEventos);
```

And here the code where the JS create the events:

```
var globalEventObj = {};

function showEvents() {
   let sidebarEvents = document.getElementById("sidebarEvents");
   let objWithDate = globalEventObj[selectedDate.toDateString()];

   sidebarEvents.innerHTML = "";

   if (objWithDate) {
      let eventsCount = 0;
      for (key in globalEventObj[selectedDate.toDateString()]) {
         let eventContainer = document.createElement("div");
         eventContainer.className = "eventCard";

         let eventHeader = document.createElement("div");
         eventHeader.className = "eventCard-header";

         let eventDescription = document.createElement("div");
         eventDescription.className = "eventCard-description";

         eventHeader.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
         eventContainer.appendChild(eventHeader);

         eventDescription.appendChild(document.createTextNode(objWithDate[key]));
         eventContainer.appendChild(eventDescription);

         let markWrapper = document.createElement("div");
         markWrapper.className = "eventCard-mark-wrapper";
         let mark = document.createElement("div");
         mark.classList = "eventCard-mark";
         markWrapper.appendChild(mark);
         eventContainer.appendChild(markWrapper);

         sidebarEvents.appendChild(eventContainer);

         eventsCount++;
      }
      let emptyFormMessage = document.getElementById("emptyFormTitle");
      emptyFormMessage.innerHTML = ${eventsCount} eventos;
   } else {
      let emptyMessage = document.createElement("div");
      emptyMessage.className = "empty-message";
      emptyMessage.innerHTML = "No tienes turnos este día";
      sidebarEvents.appendChild(emptyMessage);
      let emptyFormMessage = document.getElementById("emptyFormTitle");
      emptyFormMessage.innerHTML = "No existen turnos";
   }
}
```

Comment: json_encode the list of events from the database and inject it into the JS so it can use it to build the list.

Comment: what does `globalEventObj[selectedDate.toDateString()]` gives you ?

Comment: @Swati This object return the date selected in this format " "Thu Mar 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)"

Comment: from where ? are you using ajax to return datas ?

Comment: I'm using ajax from send the info at a php file... This file saves the info in a mysql table. For return the info i'm using php and the function json_encode, then i'm using a <p> for insert the array and take the info with js usin .textContent;
I upload all code at github, this is the link: https://github.com/alanezequielbua/Agenda1